# Google sheets recalculate manually

Tags: google-sheets

Is there any way to disable automatic refreshing and recalculating a function in Google Sheets?

Working with large sheets that include some functions is super slow, and no need to keep refreshing cells when opening The file. I was wondering if there is any way to disable functions to be refreshed automatically, and enable them again only when needed?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't but you could add this feature by using Google Apps Script.

If your spreadsheet is not "excesively complex" you could save a map of references and the corresponing formulas using the Properties Service, otherwise you might have to save this map somethere else.

Another option is to save this map using the [Class Developer Metadata](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/developer-metadata)

Related

- [Ho do I stop and start autoupdating in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30373782/1595451)
- [Google Apps Script in Google Sheet - Convert formulas to static values - cell function to value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33963765/1595451)
- [In google sheets can I wrap a standard function in a custom function to control when it is run?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55905947/1595451)
- [How can I disable automatic recalculation on google sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808568/1595451)
- [how to make a custom function NOT recalculate in Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63431445/1595451)